# Facebook Sharer Can't See OG:IMAGE Tag At First Check

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sharer

I am trying to share this url via facebook(change RANDOM_STRING with any random string because of facebook cache):

```
http://www.ikposta.com/blog/goster/72/test_RANDOM_STRING
```

at first try facebook will decide picture which is there is a men. Refresh facebook page and try again share with same url at this time picture will be changed and you will see keyboard image which is correct image.

`og:image` tag is always correct why this is happening ?

How can I prevent ?

Comment: Your URL doesn't work. And what is your problem? On first loading the picture is a man but should be a keyboard? And on every other loading it's the keyboard?

Comment: Have you tried debugging with Facebook Object Debugger?

Comment: Maybe related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415566/why-doesnt-like-button-work-immediately

Comment: Hi @mTarun, did you find solution of it?

Answer (score 1):

Run your URL through the [Facebook Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) to make sure that your OG image tag is correctly being picked up by Facebook. This will also force a re-cache of the image.

I ran it through quickly and there were a couple errors that came up. Primarily missing URL and title OG tags. You'll want to have these to avoid circular redirects. See here: [Debugged](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.ikposta.com/blog/goster/72/test_RANDOM_STRING)

I would personally remove that cache bust all together. It's confusing Facebook because it looks like a directory. If anything, use a query string.